# Aggregating values in hashmap by keys

Tags: java, collections

Consider a simple `HashMap<Integer,Integer>`. How can I get all the values stored against keys which are multiple of, say 5? I have worked on `Java` and `Collections` for some time now, but suddenly I am clueless.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Salil

Comment: Java 8 will have some fancy ways to do this.

Comment: Is [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544122/aggregating-hashmap-values-by-keys-based-on-a-pattern) in your class?

Comment: @Bohemian: [That guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544122/aggregating-hashmap-values-by-keys-based-on-a-pattern) is me, not someone else. The same question got posted twice, so I deleted one copy. This is not a homework question. I work in industry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  if (entry.getKey() % 5 == 0) {
     values.add(entry.getValue());
  }
}
```

FWIW, a comparable Java 8 approach might look like

```
map.entrySet().stream()
   .filter(entry -> entry.getKey() % 5 == 0)
   .map(Entry<Integer, Integer>::getValue)
   .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Oh, Ok. So no other way than iterating over the set?

Comment: No.  Why would you expect there to be another way?

Comment: For better efficiency.

Comment: @Salil: What would you expect that "better efficiency" method to actually do in terms of the data structures?

Comment: For better efficiency use a LinkedHashMap. There's no other way to check all the keys except to check all of them.

Comment: @Louis: I was only wondering if one can generalize `HashMap.get(key)` to `HashMap.get(pattern)`. That way, the complexity is pushed inside, and the iteration would run over HashMap.table[pattern] rather than over the complete entrySet

Comment: @Salil: No, that wouldn't really work -- to say nothing of that running over `HashMap.table` is equivalent to iterating over the `entrySet`.  Your hash table isn't going to correspond to "keys mod 5," there's nothing more efficient you can do.

Comment: I see. thanks for clarifying @Louis. Judging by your authority on the subject, I am considering it as the best possible answer, and accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Guava has a few helper methods to help you achieve this. In particular, [`Maps.filterKeys(Map, Predicate)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#filterKeys%28java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29)

```
// populate a Map
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(3, 0);
map.put(15, 42);
map.put(75, 1234);

// filter it
Map<Integer, Integer> filtered = Maps.filterKeys(map, new Predicate<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Integer input) {
        return input % 5 == 0; // filter logic
    }
});

// get the values
System.out.println(filtered.values());
```

prints

```
[1234, 42]
```

As Louis notes, ["this isn't actually more efficient -- or even shorter -- than the "traditional" for-each approach."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544103/aggregating-values-in-hashmap-by-keys/21544167?noredirect=1#comment32534268_21544167)

Comment: It's worth noting that this isn't actually shorter than the "traditional" for-each approach.